# R hurdle: In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced

Tags: r

I have a dataframe from csv, that consist 1 dependent variable (y) and 7 independent variables (x's). Y consist of many zeros. So I want to use hurdle (truncated poisson for count and logit for zero)
This is my code

```
library(pscl)
data <-  read.csv("D:/data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
head(data)
x1 <- data$X1
x2 <- data$X2
x3 <- data$X3
x4 <- data$X4
x5 <- data$X5
x6 <- data$X6
x7 <- data$X7
y <- data$Y

data <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,y)
head(data)
hurdlepois <-hurdle(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7, data=data)
summary(hurdlepois)
```

The results is there are coefficients, but there are NaNs in std.error. And I get Warning

```
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced
```

Someone suggest me to do this code

```
ctrl <- hurdle.control(method = "L-BFGS-B")
ctrl$reltol <- NULL
hurdlepois <-hurdle(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7, data=data, control = ctrl)
summary(hurdlepois)
```

But I get this error when I run hurdlepois <-hurdle(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7, data=data, control = ctrl)

```
Error in optim(fn = countDist, gr = countGrad, par = c(start$count, if (dist ==  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

Can you help me please? Please give me detail solution what should I do, because I'm beginner and so desperate. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible example. Usually, this occurs if some regressors are poorly scaled (e.g., in thousands or millions), when there is a lack of variation in some regressors in some parts of the model etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir :)
You are right